# Python & MySQL connector: AttributeError: 'CMySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

- I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

  - I am using mysql-connector-python to connect Python to MySQL.
  - I am using Python 3.6.7, and have installed mysql-connector-python.
  - I have installed mysql-connector-python-py3_8.0.13-1ubuntu18.10_all.deb.

When running my Python script, the mysql.connector module appears to load correctly, but the script fails when it hits cursor.next() with the following traceback error:

AttributeError: 'CMySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'next'

Interestingly, the same python script works perfectly when I run it with Python 2.7.

```
import mysql.connector
import reddit_constants as rc
import logging


class MysqlManager:
    def __init__(self, database, username, password, logger):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.database = database
        self.logger = logger

    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            self.create_db()
            self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                user=self.username,
                passwd=self.password,
                auth_plugin='mysql_native_password',
                database=self.database
            )
            if self.conn.is_connected():
                self.logger.info('Connected to reddit database')
            return self
        except:
            self.logger.error('Error: Could not connect to reddit database')
            self.conn.close()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.conn.close()

    def create_db(self):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            user=self.username,
            passwd=self.password,
            auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
        )

        cursor = mydb.cursor()

        cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + self.database)

        mydb.close()

    def create_tables(self):
        if not self.conn.is_connected():
            self.logger.Error('Error in MySqlManager: You must initialize the connection to MySql')
            return

        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subreddit 
            (
                subreddit_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
                subreddit_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                subscriptions INT,
                PRIMARY KEY (subreddit_id)
            )
        """)

        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post (
                post_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
                subreddit_id INT NOT NULL,
                post_title VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
                post_ref VARCHAR(2084),
                comments_ref VARCHAR(2084),
                username VARCHAR(30),
                created_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (post_id),
                FOREIGN KEY (subreddit_id) REFERENCES subreddit(subreddit_id),
                CONSTRAINT UC_post UNIQUE(subreddit_id, post_title, username, created_time)
            )
        """)

        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post_history (
                post_history_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
                post_id INT,
                votes INT,
                ranks INT,
                updated_time DATETIME,
                PRIMARY KEY (post_history_id),
                FOREIGN KEY (post_id) references post(post_id)
            )    
        """)

        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comment 
            (
                comment_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
                post_id INT NOT NULL,
                subreddit_id INT NOT NULL,
                username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                created_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (comment_id),
                FOREIGN KEY (subreddit_id) REFERENCES subreddit(subreddit_id),
                FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post(post_id),
                CONSTRAINT UC_comment UNIQUE(subreddit_id, post_id, username, created_time)
            )
        """)

        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comment_history 
            (
                comment_history_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
                comment_id INT,
                message TEXT,
                votes INT,
                updated_time DATETIME,
                PRIMARY KEY (comment_history_id),
                FOREIGN KEY (comment_id) references comment(comment_id)
            )    
        """)

        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS youtube_info
            (
                youtube_info_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
                post_id INT,
                video_title TEXT,
                publish_date DATETIME,
                view_count INT,
                like_count INT,
                dislike_count INT,
                comment_count INT,
                PRIMARY KEY (youtube_info_id),
                FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post(post_id),
                CONSTRAINT UC_youtube_info UNIQUE(post_id)
            )
        """)

    def insert_subreddits(self, posts):
        if not self.conn.is_connected():
            self.logger.Error('Error in MySqlManager: You must initialize the connection to MySql')
            return
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        for post in posts:
            values = (post[rc.SUBREDDIT_KEY], None)
            query = """
                INSERT IGNORE INTO subreddit (subreddit_name, subscriptions)
                VALUES(%s, %s)
            """
            cursor.execute(query, values)
            self.conn.commit()
            new_id = cursor.lastrowid
            if new_id == 0:
                id_query = "SELECT subreddit_id FROM subreddit WHERE subreddit_name = %s"
                id_values = (post[rc.SUBREDDIT_KEY],)
                cursor.execute(id_query, id_values)
                new_id = cursor.next()[0]
            post[rc.SUBREDDIT_ID] = new_id
        self.logger.info(' - Inserted subreddits from page successfully')

    def insert_posts(self, posts):
        if not self.conn.is_connected():
            self.logger.Error('Error in MySqlManager: You must initialize the connection to MySql')
            return
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        for post in posts:
            post_values = (post[rc.SUBREDDIT_ID],
                           post[rc.POST_TITLE_KEY],
                           post[rc.POST_REF_KEY],
                           post[rc.COMMENTS_REF_KEY],
                           post[rc.USER_KEY],
                           post[rc.CREATED_TIMESTAMP_KEY])
            post_query = """
                INSERT IGNORE INTO post (subreddit_id, post_title, post_ref,
                comments_ref, username, created_time)
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
            """

            cursor.execute(post_query, post_values)
            self.conn.commit()
            new_id = cursor.lastrowid

            if new_id == 0:
                id_query = """
                    SELECT post_id 
                    FROM post 
                    WHERE subreddit_id = %s
                    AND post_title = %s
                    AND username = %s
                    AND created_time = %s
                """
                id_values = (post[rc.SUBREDDIT_ID],
                             post[rc.POST_TITLE_KEY],
                             post[rc.USER_KEY],
                             post[rc.CREATED_TIMESTAMP_KEY])
                cursor.execute(id_query, id_values)
                new_id = cursor.next()[0]
            post[rc.POST_ID] = new_id

            post_history_values = (post[rc.POST_ID],
                                   post[rc.VOTE_KEY],
                                   post[rc.RANK_KEY])

            post_history_query = """
                INSERT INTO post_history (post_id, votes, ranks, updated_time) 
                (SELECT %s, %s, %s, NOW())
            """

            cursor.execute(post_history_query, post_history_values)
            self.conn.commit()
        self.logger.info(' - Inserted posts from page successfully')

    def insert_video_info(self, video_info):
        if not self.conn.is_connected():
            self.logger.Error('MySqlManager: You must initialize the connection to MySql')
            return
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        video_info_values = (video_info[rc.POST_ID],
                             video_info[rc.YOUTUBE_TITLE_KEY],
                             video_info[rc.YOUTUBE_PUBLISHED_KEY],
                             video_info[rc.YOUTUBE_VIEW_COUNT_KEY],
                             video_info[rc.YOUTUBE_LIKE_KEY],
                             video_info[rc.YOUTUBE_DISLIKE_KEY],
                             video_info[rc.YOUTUBE_COMMENT_KEY])

        video_info_query = """
            INSERT IGNORE INTO youtube_info (post_id, 
                video_title,
                publish_date,
                view_count,
                like_count,
                dislike_count,
                comment_count)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        """

        cursor.execute(video_info_query, video_info_values)
        self.conn.commit()

    def insert_comments(self, comments, post):
        if not self.conn.is_connected():
            self.logger.Error('Error in MySqlManager: You must initialize the connection to MySql')
            return
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        for comment in comments:

            comment_values = (post[rc.POST_ID],
                              post[rc.SUBREDDIT_ID],
                              comment[rc.USER_KEY],
                              comment[rc.CREATED_TIMESTAMP_KEY])
            comment_query = """
                INSERT IGNORE INTO comment (post_id, subreddit_id, username, created_time) 
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
            """

            cursor.execute(comment_query, comment_values)
            self.conn.commit()
            new_id = cursor.lastrowid
            if new_id == 0:
                id_query = """
                    SELECT comment_id 
                    FROM comment 
                    WHERE post_id = %s
                    AND username = %s
                    AND created_time = %s
                """
                id_values = (post[rc.POST_ID],
                             comment[rc.USER_KEY],
                             comment[rc.CREATED_TIMESTAMP_KEY])
                cursor.execute(id_query, id_values)
                new_id = cursor.next()[0]
            comment[rc.COMMENT_ID] = new_id

            comment_history_values = (comment[rc.COMMENT_ID],
                                      comment[rc.VOTE_KEY],
                                      comment[rc.MESSAGE_KEY])
            comment_history_query = """
                INSERT INTO comment_history (comment_id, votes, message, updated_time) 
                (SELECT %s, %s, %s, NOW())  
            """
            cursor.execute(comment_history_query, comment_history_values)
            self.conn.commit()
        self.logger.info('Inserted comments from {} post successfully'.format(post[rc.POST_REF_KEY]))


def mysql_test_suite():
    import csv
    with MysqlManager(rc.DATABASE_NAME,
                              rc.DB_USERNAME,
                              rc.DB_PASSWORD,
                              logging.getLogger('test')) as mysql_test:

        with open("testfiles/posts.csv", "r") as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            posts = list(reader)

        mysql_test.insert_subreddits(posts)
        mysql_test.insert_posts(posts)

        for post_test in posts:
            assert post_test[rc.SUBREDDIT_ID] > 0
            assert post_test[rc.POST_ID] > 0

        with open("testfiles/comments.csv", "r") as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            comments = list(reader)

        mysql_test.insert_comments(comments, posts[0])

        for comment in comments:
            assert comment[rc.COMMENT_ID] > 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mysql_test_suite()
    print("All mysql tests ran successfully")
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html) not list it.

Comment: can you provide code ?

Comment: I see that .next is not in the documentation, but why does it work under python 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As roganjosh mentioned, next() was not an attribute. I used fetchone() instead.

Answer (score 1):

next() seems not available in mysql-connector-python
but it's available in mysql-connector librairy.
try

```
pip uninstall mysql-connector-python
pip install mysql-connector
```